# Multiplication of the type self.w.value[x]

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I am reading a segment of a program that says

```
self.w.value[x]
```

Here, w.value has the shape (2000, 30)

x is an input, which has the shape (200, )

After calling self.w.value[x], I get an output that is (200, 30).

For the life of me I cannot figure out just what kind of multiplication took place. How does a (2000, 30)
array take in a  (200, ) array and produces (200, 30)?

Does anyone know what happened?

---

The output is shown here:

[image]

Comment: There was no multiplication.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks. This must be an indexing instead. However, I still cannot figure out where 2000 disappeared into 200

Comment: Did you read this already? https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using x as the indices for w.value.
This will return the values of w.value that have the index described in x.

Comment: So how does this indexing work? The matrix w.values has 2000 rows, and 30 columns, and I have 200 indices. How do I produce a (200,30) array?

Comment: every element in x represents a row(1,300) that is returned. So the first row in your answer will be the 634th row in w.value.

Comment: @Norman. Check out the docs (probably where you should have started): https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html